# javascript form validation refreshes page

Tags: javascript, validation, forms, client, client-side

```
function subVal()
{
    if (document.forms['loginform'].name.value == '' || document.forms['loginform'].uid.value == '')
    {
        if (document.forms['loginform'].uid.value == '')
    {
        document.getElementById('afterpass').innerHTML = 'FORGOT PASSWORD';
    }
    if (document.forms['loginform'].name.value == '')
    {
        document.getElementById('aftername').innerHTML = 'FORGOT USERNAME';
    }
    }
    if (document.forms['loginform'].name.value != '' && document.forms['loginform'].uid.value != '')
    {
        document.forms['loginform'].submit();
    }
}
```

when i try to validate, it does what it's supposed to do (insert the HTML) then refreshes. how can i stop this?

Comment: What is the form's `action` set to?

Comment: Show us the markup of button on click of which you are calling this function.

Comment: itself... the action is the page

Comment: @sdleihssirhc - Action would not cause this problem. I am sure button is marked as submit button.

Comment: just changed it to `<form action='javascript:subVal()' method='post' name='loginform'><input type='text' name='name' /><div id='aftername'></div><input type='password' name='uid' /><div id='afterpass'></div><button onclick='subVal()'>Submit</button></form>`

Comment: I guess you need to return false, if your validation is failing.

Comment: then when i submit it nothing happens

Comment: Got the problem. You have created a button without specifying its type. Specify the type as "button". On its click call the subVal(). Make the action of form whatever it was earlier, rather than calling subVal().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function subVal()
{ 

    if (document.getElementById('name').value == '' && document.getElementById('uid').value == '')
    {
        document.getElementById('aftername').innerHTML = 'FORGOT USERNAME';

        document.getElementById('afterpass').innerHTML = 'FORGOT PASSWORD';
            return false;
    }   
    else if ( document.getElementById('uid').value == '' )
        {
            document.getElementById('afterpass').innerHTML = 'FORGOT PASSWORD';
            return false;
        }
    else if (document.getElementById('name').value == '')
        { 
            document.getElementById('aftername').innerHTML = 'FORGOT USERNAME';
            return false;
        }
    else
  {
        document.forms['loginform'].submit();
    }
}


</script>

<form method='post' name='loginform'>
<input type='text' name='name' id="name" />
<div id='aftername'></div>
<input type='password' name='uid' id="uid" />
<div id='afterpass'></div>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick='subVal()'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function subVal()
{
    if (document.forms['loginform'].name.value == '' || document.forms['loginform'].uid.value == '')
    {
    if (document.forms['loginform'].uid.value == '')
    {
        document.getElementById('afterpass').innerHTML = 'FORGOT PASSWORD';
        return false;
    }
    if (document.forms['loginform'].name.value == '')
    {
        document.getElementById('aftername').innerHTML = 'FORGOT USERNAME';
        return false;
    }
    }
    if (document.forms['loginform'].name.value != '' && document.forms['loginform'].uid.value != '')
    {
        document.forms['loginform'].submit();
    }
}
```